# Setup Android emulator for tablet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, tablet

I'm developing an Android app on a tablet. I was trying to use the emulator for development. But, the orientation, when the app is running on a tablet, is not fixed.

For example: when a button is attached to the bottom of a screen layout (let's say MainActivity), and I'm trying to press on it, the press will be affect the center of the screen (vertically).

Therefore, I can't test any button pressed or other views. Does anyone knows how to fix that? Can't find any useful reference online.

Comment: You can disable clicks for the View in Background.

Comment: Can you please explain how, and how will it make any changes?